# Calling c# function in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've been trying to call a c# function in javascript this way :

```
function x() {
    PageMethods.F1(onSucess, onError);

    function onSucess(result) {
       alert('Success');
    }
    function onError(result) {
       alert('Something wrong.');
    }
}
```

```
[WebMethod]
public static boolean F1()
{
    return true;
}
```

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  OnClientClick="x(); return false"    Text="Button"  />
```

But I don't get any result, I mean neither of the alert messages pops up. What exactly is wrong ?

Comment: Do you get a js error in the console?

Comment: @Mario : No, I get nothing, the button doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: @Mario: What would be the best way to call a c# function in js ?

Comment: Try `public static string F1() { return "Hello"; }` instead, see if that works.

Comment: @Mario: No it doesn't work :D.

Comment: Did you set `EnablePageMethods = true` on the ScriptManager?

Comment: @Mario: would you please explain a little more, this could be the problem

Comment: @Mario: Thank you very much indeed, this was the problem, now it is working very well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `EnablePageMethods` to **true** on the `ScriptManager`.

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="True" />
```